# How to add point attributes to containing polygon?

Tags: qgis, polygon, spatial-join

I have three layers in a QGIS project:

layer 1 is a boundary layer of polygons each with and id I will call "p_id"

layer 2 is a point layer each with an id called "p_id"

layer 3 is a .csv layer with count data that I am joining to both layer 1 and layer 2 on p_id (both the points and the polygons are the same type of thing)

What I would like to do is for every polygon add the count data from each point contained within it to the polygons count data

Is there a tool in QGIS that will allow me to do that?

Comment: Welcome to GIS.se! Have a look at two separate steps, which are answered elsewhere: joining CSV to layer, and 'points in polygon'.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you want to insert into the polygon table a new attribute which holds the total of all the count data for all the points contained in that polygon.

These kinds of aggregates are easy to do in a spatial database, like Spatialite. Here's what I would do:
First import the two shapefiles and the csv into a Spatialite database. (there are easy to use Import buttons on in the Spatialite_gui application).

So you should have a spatial table of points, we'll call it "pts", with an id field called "p_id". You have another spatial table of polygons called "polys". And a third, non-spatial table "count_data" with an id column called "p_id" and an integer column named "count". So:

1. Add a new column in the pts table and the polygon table to hold the count values

   ALTER TABLE pts ADD COLUMN count INTEGER;

   ALTER TABLE polys ADD COLUMN count INTEGER;
2. Get the values from the csv table into the pts spatial table, with the p_id column:

   UPDATE pts SET count=(SELECT count FROM count_data WHERE count_data.p_id = pts.p_id)
3. Now do a spatial aggregation of the count values for each polygon

   UPDATE polys SET count=(SELECT SUM(count) FROM pts WHERE ST_Contains(polys.geometry, pts.geometry);